# How to drop rows not containing string type in a column in Pandas?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with four columns. I read it like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', error_bad_lines=False, sep='\t', header=None, names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Now, field `C` contains string values. But in some rows there are non-string type (floats or numbers) values. How to drop those rows? I'm using version 0.18.1 of Pandas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 1.2, 'g']], columns=list('ABCD'))
print df

   A  B    C  D
0  a  b    c  d
1  e  f  1.2  g
```

Notice you can see what the individual cell types are.

```
print type(df.loc[0, 'C']), type(df.loc[1, 'C'])

<type 'str'> <type 'float'>
```

mask and slice

```
print df.loc[df.C.apply(type) != float]

   A  B  C  D
0  a  b  c  d
```

more general

```
print df.loc[df.C.apply(lambda x: not isinstance(x, (float, int)))]

   A  B  C  D
0  a  b  c  d
```

you could also use `float` as an attempt to determine if it can be a float.

```
def try_float(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False

print df.loc[~df.C.apply(try_float)]

   A  B  C  D
0  a  b  c  d
```

The problem with this approach is that you'll exclude strings that can be interpreted as floats.

Comparing times for the few options I've provided and also jezrael's solution with small dataframes.

[image]

For a dataframe with 500,000 rows:

[image]

Checking if its type is float seems to be most performant with is numeric right behind it.  If you need to check int and float, I'd go with jezrael's answer.  If you can get away with checking for float, use that one.

Comment: Is there a reason to match "not float or int" instead of "is str"?  `df.loc[df.C.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with  `mask` created by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` - you get `NaN` where are string values. Then check [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':['a',8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5]})
print (df)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  a  1
1  2  5  8  3
2  3  6  9  5

print (pd.to_numeric(df.C, errors='coerce'))
0    NaN
1    8.0
2    9.0
Name: C, dtype: float64

print (pd.to_numeric(df.C, errors='coerce').isnull())
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: C, dtype: bool

print (df[pd.to_numeric(df.C, errors='coerce').isnull()])
   A  B  C  D
0  1  4  a  1
```

Comment: Is this method efficient for a data frame with 500,000 rows?

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas.DataFrame.[select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) method.
Ex.

```
df.select_dtypes(exclude='object')
         or
df.select_dtypes(include=['int64','float','int'])
```